# Remove duplicates from python dataframe list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df where each row is a list of words. The list has duplicate words. I want to remove duplicate words.

I tried using dict.fromkeys(listname) in a for loop to iterate over each row in the df. But this splits the words into alphabets

```
filepath = "C:/abc5/Python/Clustering/output2.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filepath,encoding='windows-1252')

df["newlist"] = df["text_lemmatized"]
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    l = df["text_lemmatized"][i]
    df["newlist"][i] = list(dict.fromkeys(l))

print(df)
```

Expected result is ==>

```
['clear', 'pending', 'order', 'pending', 'order']   ['clear', 'pending', 'order']
 ['pending', 'activation', 'clear', 'pending']   ['pending', 'activation', 'clear']
```

Actual result is

```
['clear', 'pending', 'order', 'pending', 'order']  ...   [[, ', c, l, e, a, r, ,,  , p, n, d, i, g, o, ]]
['pending', 'activation', 'clear', 'pending', ...  ...  [[, ', p, e, n, d, i, g, ,,  , a, c, t, v, o, ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `set` to remove duplicates.

Also you don't need the for loop

```
  df["newlist"] = list(set( df["text_lemmatized"] ))
```

Comment: I get the error...ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: What error? You need to provide at least the error message

Comment: Error I get is "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index "

Answer (score 4):

Just use `series.map` and `np.unique`

Your sample data:

```
Out[43]:
                           text_lemmatized
0  [clear, pending, order, pending, order]
1    [pending, activation, clear, pending]

df.text_lemmatized.map(np.unique)

Out[44]:
    0         [clear, order, pending]
    1    [activation, clear, pending]
    Name: val, dtype: object
```

If you prefer it isn't sorted, use `pd.unique`

```
df.text_lemmatized.map(pd.unique)

Out[51]:
0         [clear, pending, order]
1    [pending, activation, clear]
Name: text_lemmatized, dtype: object
```

Comment: There is no error but it does not remove the duplicates. Does not work.

Comment: @AnoopMahajan: it's weird! it works on my system with your sample. Have you assign it back as `df['newlist'] = df.text_lemmatized.map(pd.unique)`

Answer (score 0):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset ="text_lemmatized", 
                     keep = First, inplace = True)
```

keep = First, means keep the first occurrence

Comment: This does not work and gives me the same error: "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index"...

Answer (score 0):

Problem is there are not lists, but strings, so is necessary convert each value to list by `ast.literal_eval`, then is possible convert values to `set`s for remove duplicates:

```
import ast

df['newlist'] = df['text_lemmatized'].map(lambda x: list(set(ast.literal_eval(x))))
print(df)
                           text_lemmatized                       newlist
0  [clear, pending, order, pending, order]       [clear, pending, order]
1    [pending, activation, clear, pending]  [clear, activation, pending]
```

Or use `dict.fromkeys`:

```
f = lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys(ast.literal_eval(x)))
df['newlist'] = df['text_lemmatized'].map(f)
```

Another idea is convert column `text_lemmatized` to lists in one step and then remove duplicates in another step, advantage is lists in column `text_lemmatized` for next processing:

```
df['text_lemmatized'] = df['text_lemmatized'].map(ast.literal_eval)
df['newlist'] = df['text_lemmatized'].map(lambda x: list(set(x)))
```

EDIT:

After some discussion solution is:

```
df['newlist'] = df['text_lemmatized'].map(lambda x: list(set(x)))
```

Comment: I am sorry jezrael...When i incorporated this in my full code, it is now giving me an error as "ValueError: malformed node or string: ['clear', 'pending', 'order', 'pending', 'order']

Comment: @AnoopMahajan - How working last solution with change `df['text_lemmatized'] = df['text_lemmatized'].map(ast.literal_eval)` to `df['text_lemmatized'] = df['text_lemmatized'].str.strip("[]").str.split(', ')` ?

Comment: tried the following, df["newlist"] = df["text_lemmatized"]
df['text_lemmatized'] = df['text_lemmatized'].str.strip("[]").str.split(', ')
df['newlist'] = df['text_lemmatized'].map(lambda x: list(set(x)))...I get an error as "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas"

Comment: @AnoopMahajan - What is `print (type(df['text_lemmatized'].iat[0]))` ?

Comment: print returns <class 'list'>

Comment: So need only `df['newlist'] = df['text_lemmatized'].map(lambda x: list(set(x)))`

Comment: how to apply same function in multiple columns

Comment: @dondapati - Use `applymap` like `df[['newlist', 'col1', 'col2']] = df[['newlist', 'col1', 'col2']].applymap(lambda x: list(set(x)))`

Answer (score 0):

Your code for removing duplicates seems fine.
I tried following and it worked well.
Guess the problem is the way you are appending the list in the dataframe column.

```
`list_from_df = [['clear', 'pending', 'order', 'pending', 'order'],
            ['pending', 'activation', 'clear', 'pending']] 

list_with_unique_words = []

for x in list_from_df:

    unique_words = list(dict.fromkeys(x))
    list_with_unique_words.append(unique_words)

print(list_with_unique_words)
```

> > > output [['clear', 'pending', 'order'], ['pending', 'activation', 'clear']]

```
df["newlist"] = list_with_unique_words

df
```

`

[image: my final df]

Comment: This does not seem to work and gives me the same error as before where it splits each word into alphabets

Answer (score 0):

Solution is ==>

```
import pandas as pd
filepath = "C:/abc5/Python/Clustering/output2.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filepath,encoding='windows-1252')
df["newlist"] = df["text_lemmatized"]
df['newlist'] = df['text_lemmatized'].map(lambda x: list(set(x)))
print(df)
```

Thanks to jezrael and all others who helped narrow down to this solution