# How to remove duplicate values from the python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with duplicate values in either list or string format.

```
df = Name                  Email                            years        score 
     john           [a@g.com,b@g.com, a@g.com]                8           good
               
     
     [devan,smith ,devan]   [a@g.com]                   [8,6,8]           good
```

I want to remove duplicate values within that particular cell, not to compare corresponding to different cells.

```
df_updated = Name                  Email                      years        score
             john           [a@g.com,b@g.com]                 8            good
               
     
          [devan,smith]          [a@g.com]                   [8,6]         good
```

Comment: Your input data is ambiguous, please provide it as dataframe or dictionary Use `df.to_dict('list')` and update your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for elementwise processing with custom function for remove duplicates if type is `list`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John', ['aa','devan','smith','devan']],
                   'years':[8, [8,6,8]]})

print (df)
                        Name      years
0                       John          8
1  [aa, devan, smith, devan]  [8, 6, 8]

df1 = df.applymap(lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys(x)) if isinstance(x, list) else x)
print (df1)
                 Name   years
0                John       8
1  [aa, devan, smith]  [8, 6]
```

If ordering is not important use `set`s:

```
df2 = df.applymap(lambda x: list(set(x)) if isinstance(x, list) else x)
print (df2)
                 Name   years
0                John       8
1  [devan, smith, aa]  [8, 6]
```

Comment: looks like [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57107622) ;) I thought of the exact same solution and I imagined it already existed

Comment: @mozway - hmm, partly.

Comment: I would say fully "After some discussion solution is: `df['newlist'] = df['text_lemmatized'].map(lambda x: list(set(x)))`" except `map` in place of `applymap` and `set` instead of `dict.from_keys`, but you also showed those in the dupe

Comment: @mozway - ya, partly dupe. part solution is same, part not.

Answer (score 0):

Without the main dataframe, it is hard to guess how your dataframe functions. Anyway, here is what you probably need:

```py
df["Email"].apply(set)
```

Note that **Email** column should be list. If you are interested in removing duplicated from other columns, let's say **Name** column, try replacing **Name** in place of **Email** in the abovementioned cell.